# Where did "Dungeon Breaks", a.k.a monsters flooding out of a dungeon, come from?

Tags: history-of, trope, litrpg

Where did "Dungeon Breaks", a.k.a monsters flooding out of a dungeon, come from?

We know where the term for [monster-zone "dungeons"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/why-does-dungeon-mean-the-places-adventurers-go-to-kill-stuff) came from, since that was my question...

But "dungeon breaks" as in monster floods coming out of dungeons, I don't think came from DnD... And it usually happens in LitRPGs and other worlds with Dungeons in them, but it doesn't seem common in those stories either?

Also doesn't seem to be coming from RPG Games?

When did that idea of "dungeons", getting the ability to suddenly spew out monsters, start being used? It's not just one person coming up with this, it's a propagating innovation in the "stories with adventurers going in dungeons", or maybe just LitRPG, genre. So who started it? I guess it's to increase tension in the world...

For examples:

[Solo Levelling](https://solo-leveling.fandom.com/wiki/Dungeons):

> If it is not, then it will undergo what's called a dungeon break, meaning that the monsters inside the dungeon will be able to cross over to the human world and attack the civilian population.

[Why Are My Skills So Weird 1](https://machineslicedbread.xyz/why-are-my-skills-so-weird-1/):

> Dungeon breaks. They were called like that.
> Occasionally, extremely strong and violent monsters emerged from them. Some monsters were so strong that normal weapons were useless against them. When calamity-type monsters started to appear, only weapons of mass destruction could kill them.

[49. The Dungeon Break(5) - The Strongest Skill Getting rich while becoming stronger](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/18312/the-strongest-skill-getting-rich-while-becoming/chapter/289602/49-the-dungeon-break5):

> Everyone’s face paled after hearing this. Dungeon break was not something should be taken lightly. If it wasn’t controlled properly then thousands of people might die from it. Thousands of monsters would pour out of it, creating damages wherever they go. It was truly befitting of a calamity comparable to natural disasters.

Comment: Revelation 9:2 doesn't seem to quite fit (and might not be an on-topic answer anyhow), just thought I'd eliminate that one.

Comment: *Black Easter* would be on topic, if it were an answer. But I don't think this is a real question, because I don't believe "Dungeon Breaks* is a real thing.

Comment: @user14111 - Here's one example. Will add more. stop at 3.

Comment: See also [hellmouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmouth), and [pandemonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pand%C3%A6monium_(Paradise_Lost)).

Comment: I'm not familiar with these works, but does this question want an anime or manga tag?

Comment: Hmm... I feel like this one is tricky without further definition. As others have noted, there are parallels with "Hell on Earth" scenarios. Also, influx from parallel worlds, or even invasions or refugee waves from other nations. Settings with capital D Dungeons are a bit different due to the magical source of monsters. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Might just be LitRPGs... Since my three examples are all LitRPGs...

Comment: Ghostbusters, maybe? The mid-movie scene where all the ghosts break out of containment?

Comment: Well, I would have posted an answer to the effect "8th century BCE, the story of [Anesidora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora) (Pandora)" but there's no mention of dungeons, just evils ("she who sends up gifts [from bellow]" the meaning of Anesidora).

Comment: Feels like a term from mostly Korean webnovels/comics, from what I can tell. "Seoul Station's Necromancer" might be the first one to have used the term, in 2016, and "Solo Levelling" then coped from that.

Comment: This sounds to me like a specific variation of the global, limited-time events that show up in some MMORPGs (not a real MMO, but the "goblin king event" from Log Horizon comes to mind) that caught on.